# Use of PublicFieldUberspect in velocity for exposing public variables of java

Tags: java, html, velocity

I am using velocity template along with java, my question is similar to the following:
[previous question](http://%3Chttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013971/how-to-print-a-list-of-objects-in-a-velocity-template/15029189#15029189%3E?)

What I would like to know is that how can I exactly use PublicFieldUberspect, I have added the following line velocity.properties file.

> runtime.introspector.uberspect = org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.introspection.PublicFieldUberspect

Can I get some help regarding how can I add required code in java/html files?
I am not clear about how I should use the given documentation:

[PublicFieldUberspect](http://maven-doccheck.sourceforge.net/samples/ShinobuDemo/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/introspection/PublicFieldUberspect.html)

Do I need to extend the class, create an object & add every public variable for exposed access?